# Can a PHP script talk to a C program?

Tags: php, c

I have a potential new project, it's an embedded Linux device that needs a web interface.  The code for the application will be running as a single process in C.  The web interface needs to be able to configure various variables in the C program.  Is there a good mechanism in PHP for communicating values from a PHP script to a C process?

TY,
Fred

Comment: This is entirely dependant on the IPC mechanisms (interprocess communication can be interlanguage; both are simply processes) that the "embedded" device provides.  Embedded could refer to a car's computer or an x86 device running Windows CE -- there's a big difference!

Comment: Sure, I should have been more explicit.  I'm running embedded Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i have done it before.

You need to use TCP connections between the web server and the C application and then the two can communicate different messages and commands to each other

Comment: Yep, that's one of the better solutions :) I didn't even thought about it.

Comment: When you did the TCP connection what was the format of the data sent over it?  I am thinking that sending ASCII text with some type of command interpreter may work, e.g. "set ipaddress 192.168.0.1"...

Comment: thank you and if you need any more help, please let me know. i have made a whole php -> C application before.

Comment: I used both ASCII commands and binary commands, all depending on the message type. PHP has many functions to create both types of commands

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways but if the data isn't updated very often, you can use files. 
Second solution is to use PHP functions like `exec()` to execute you C application with proper parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can check RPC (remote procedure call) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC that could help.
I believe that easiest way to do that is using PHP exec() function, you would be able to execute c program via PHP, potential issue here is that once you run C program via PHP and PHP pass vars to C they cannot communicate any more, of course C can return some values and PHP can capture it but that is it. To pass more values you would have to execute C program all over again.
Other method would be to write your C application as PHP plugin.

Comment: OK, note that the PHP script needs to talk to a C application that's always running as a Linux process, it's not like PHP has to run the C program, it just needs to talk to it.